# How To Solve KeyError: "None of [Index(['t1'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"

Tags: python, machine-learning

I'm trying to run code found on [github](https://github.com/llSourcell/hyperparameter_optimization_strategies/blob/master/random_search.py) for Hyperparameter Optimization and grid search. So, content of my csv file is as:

[image: csv content: "treshold1.csv]

So, my code is:

```
import pandas as pd
import svm

from random import randint
from sklearn import svm

#read data
dataframe=pd.read_csv("treshold1.csv")


X = dataframe[['t1']]
y = dataframe[['t2']]
best_score = 0  
best_params = {'C': None, 'gamma': None}

#for a preset number of iterations
for i in range(10):
    #try random values for each hyperparameter
    svc = svm.SVC(C=randint(0, 9), gamma=randint(0, 3))
    svc.fit(X, y)
    score = svc.score(Xval, yval)

    if score > best_score:
        best_score = score
        best_params['C'] = C
        best_params['gamma'] = gamma

best_score, best_params
```

After run, i am getting this error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "g:/Maksa/Programiranje/Python/SI/image_quality_assessment-master/common/s.py", line 11, in <module>
    X = dataframe[['t1']]
  File "C:\Users\ftnkm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3001, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.loc._convert_to_indexer(key, axis=1, raise_missing=True)
  File "C:\Users\ftnkm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1285, in _convert_to_indexer
    return self._get_listlike_indexer(obj, axis, **kwargs)[1]
  File "C:\Users\ftnkm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1092, in _get_listlike_indexer
    keyarr, indexer, o._get_axis_number(axis), raise_missing=raise_missing
  File "C:\Users\ftnkm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1177, in _validate_read_indexer
    key=key, axis=self.obj._get_axis_name(axis)
KeyError: "None of [Index(['t1'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"
```

Comment: Kindly post the whole traceback of the error

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error message.

Comment: Can you show the actual content in the csv file? You probably exported the data from the spreadsheet incorrectly. If you are using MacOS or linux, you can print out the content by running `head treshold1.csv`

Comment: @alan.elkin and AMC, i added whole traceback.

I added content of csv file, you can see in question as image.

Comment: @Vlada _I added content of csv file, you can see in question as image._ That doesn't allow us to see the contents of the file, it looks like a screenshot of Excel. Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you just need to precise the column separator and decimal separator to the read_csv function. Note that it expects "," and "." by default.
Try with:
dataframe=pd.read_csv("treshold1.csv", sep=";", decimal=",")

Comment: Not working...  I getting this error :
ValueError: The gamma value of 0.0 is invalid. Use 'auto' to set gamma to a value of 1 / n_features.

Comment: General tip 1: Try checking the intermediate steps to see if things are going as you expect them to (check type, dtype, shape of your arrays, print stuff etc). - In your case, first make sure you read the CSV file correctly, check your X and y.
General tip 2: Try to understend what the errors you get mean. - It seems your last error simpy means that you can't have zero values in your parameters, but the `randint` in your code WILL give you zero from time to time - try to correct this.
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Your code actually can run if your input file is indeed comma delimited.

However since you are getting a `KeyError`, it is likely that your input file  `treshold1.csv` is not comma delimited.

Guessing from your screenshot of your 'csv' file content, I think your input file is probably tab delimited. Fix it and it should fix the `KeyError`.

Comment: I just replacet in csv file "," with "." and getting same error.

Comment: How did you generate the csv file? As the other SO user AMC commented, you need to show us the actual content if you want to get help.